# Spring Boot Relationship ONLY with UUIDs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, relationship

I'm new to spring boot and I want to create a OneToMany relationship between my Client class and my Purchase class. I've read so much on the internet before, but in the tutorials they always link the classes...

In my case I only want to have a clientUuid in my Purchase class, which is in relationship with the associated Client.

This is what I have in my Purchase class but I dont want to save the whole Client, I just want to save the UUID.

```
package com.michaeltillmanns.clientordersystem.contract;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.michaeltillmanns.clientordersystem.exception.ClientNotFoundException;
import com.michaeltillmanns.clientordersystem.repository.ClientRepository;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Entity(name = "PURCHASE")
public class Purchase {

    @JsonProperty("purchase_uuid")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue UUID purchaseUuid;
    @JsonProperty("date_purchased")
    private long datePurchased;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_UUID")
    private Client client;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Purchase() {}

    public Purchase(UUID purchaseUuid, long datePurchased) {
        this.purchaseUuid = purchaseUuid;
        this.datePurchased = datePurchased;
    }

    public UUID getPurchaseUuid() {
        return purchaseUuid;
    }

    public long getDatePurchased() {
        return datePurchased;
    }

    public void setPurchaseUuid(UUID purchaseUuid) {
        this.purchaseUuid = purchaseUuid;
    }

    public void setDatePurchased(long datePurchased) {
        this.datePurchased = datePurchased;
    }
}
```

Comment: it actually saves the CLIENT_UUID that is the reference to the Client. See the DB

Comment: So there will only be the client_uuid in my json object?

Comment: Wait but if i want to create a new Purchase with HTTP Post request i have to specify a whole client otherwise it throws an error

Comment: it saves the CLIENT_UUID as a reference for client in the DB but whenever you will fetch the data from Purchase it fetches the referred client data with the help of CLIENT_UUID

Comment: Okay, but i only wanna have the UUID of the client in my JSON output

Comment: In this case you have to fetch the client data with the help of UUID in your Service class